# Function pointer as member of struct in C Invalid initializer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

this is my first time posting on here, so please correct me if I'm doing anything wrong.
Ok, so I was given the following struct,function, and main:

```
typedef struct Integer50
{
// a dynamically allocated array to hold a 50
// digit integer, stored in reverse order
int *digits;
} Integer50;`
```

and

```
void big50Print(Integer50 *p)        //Unfortunately, I haven't made it to
{                                    //this part yet.  But once i get the
int i;                               //other function working, this should
if (p == NULL)                      //work fine, as it was given.
{
    printf("(null pointer)\n");
    return;
}
for (i = MAX50 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    printf("%d", p->digits[i]);
printf("\n");
}
```

and

```
int main(void)
{
Integer50 *p;
big50Print(p = parseString("01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"));
return 0;
}
```

And my goal is to create a function that parses the string into an array of integers, backwards, and returns a pointer to the newly allocated Integer50 struct, NULL if memory allocation fails, or if the input str is NULL.  So far, I have this:

```
Integer50 *parseString(char *str)   //This is the only one I can edit!
{
int len, i;
Integer50 *a[50]=malloc(sizeof(Integer50)); //this line is most likely wrong
                                            //And where the 'Invalid Initializer'
 len =strlen(str);                          //error is occuring

for (i=0; i<len; i++)            //This part works perfectly and
{                                //converts the string into integers
  a[i]= str[len-1-i]-'0';        //like it should.  The print statement here
 printf("a[%d]= %d, ", i, a[i]); //was just a test to make sure it worked.
}
 a->digits;               //also this line is probably wrong
    printf("\n");
 return a;
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm not very good with pointers yet and this proving to be quite difficult.  If anyone could clear up where I'm going wrong, it'd be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Why not simply make `digits` an array of 50 `int`s if you already know it is  always of size `50`?

Comment: Can you use the `new` keyword? I think you need to allocate one instance of `Integer50` to `a`, then allocate `a->digits` with enough space for 50 `int`s.

Comment: How would I do that? And yes, I believe I can.  As long as the only thing I edit is the parseString function

Comment: There is no function pointer anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your corrected code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX50 50

typedef struct Integer50
{
// a dynamically allocated array to hold a 50
// digit integer, stored in reverse order
int *digits;
} Integer50;


void big50Print(Integer50 *p)        //Unfortunately, I haven't made it to
{                                    //this part yet.  But once i get the
int i;                               //other function working, this should
if (p == NULL)                      //work fine, as it was given.
{
    printf("(null pointer)\n");
    return;
}
for (i = MAX50 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    printf("%d", p->digits[i]);
printf("\n");
}

Integer50 *parseString(char *str)   //This is the only one I can edit!
{
int len, i;
Integer50 *a =malloc(sizeof(Integer50)); //edited
a->digits = malloc(50 * sizeof(int));     //edited
 len =strlen(str);

for (i=0; i<len; i++)            //This part works perfectly and
{                                //converts the string into integers
  a->digits[i]= str[len-1-i]-'0';        //edited
 printf("a[%d]= %d, ", i, a->digits[i]); //edited
}
 a->digits;               //also this line is probably wrong
  printf("\n");
 return a;
}

int main(void)
{
Integer50 *p;
big50Print(p = parseString("01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"));
return 0;
}
```

The changes are

```
Integer50 *a[50]=malloc(sizeof(Integer50));
```

to

```
Integer50 *a =malloc(sizeof(Integer50));
```

because you don't want an array of Integer50s, you want an array of ints inside ONE Integer50.

so we add after this line

```
a->digits = malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
```

Similarly

```
a->digits[i]= str[len-1-i]-'0';
```

The other change is in the printf line

```
printf("%d", p->digits[i]);
```

The previous line will output gibberish. This will output the actual data you store int the int * digits.
Also remember to free the allocated memory from the heap using the free() function.
Hope that helps!

Comment: oh my god, thank you!  I've spent literally 4 hours on that, trying to figure out what I was doing wrong!

Comment: ahh, how would I go about freeing those from a separate function?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't edit main=/  So I made the following function:                Integer50 *big50Destroyer(Integer50 *p){ free(p); return NULL;}  would that suffice? or am I just writing garbage?

Comment: the return type of the function should be void since you aren't returning something